# Speedometer app not working with km/h conversion?

Tags: java, android

I am making a speedometer app for a high school science fair that displays a warning message when a speed is exceeded. When my app hits the speed limit, it does not display the message. However when I change the section `else if (location.getSpeed() >= (EditNum*3.6))` to 
`else if (location.getSpeed() >= (EditNum))` the app works. The thing is, I don't want to set the limit to MPS. How do I make the app run using the KM/H conversion (*3.6)? *PS I am a beginner programmer so sometimes I don't see obvious flaws.*

Code:

```
    TextView txt = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
    TextView war = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView2); 
    TextView war1 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView3); 
    TextView war2 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView4); 
    TextView war3 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    TextView setLimit = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView5);

    try{
    EditText Edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    String EditValue = Edit.getText().toString();

    float EditNum = Float.parseFloat(EditValue);

    setLimit.setText("Speed limit: " + (EditNum) + " km/h");


    if (location==null)
    {
        txt.setText("-.- km/h");
    }
    else if (location.getSpeed() >= (EditNum*3.6))
    {
        war.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CC0000"));
        war.setText("Warning!!!"); 
        war1.setText("Speed limit: " + (EditNum*3.6) + " km/h" );
        war2.setText("Speed: " + (location.getSpeed()*3.6) + " km/h");
        war3.setText("Speed limit exceeded by: " + (EditNum*3.6 - location.getSpeed()) + " km/h");
    }
    else
    {
        float nCurrentSpeed = location.getSpeed();
        txt.setText(nCurrentSpeed*3.6 + " km/h");
    }
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        nfe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: i'm lost inside question...

Comment: what is m/s? miles per second??what is your question exactly?

Comment: >I was wondering if theres any wasy so when it hits 5km/h it sends a message.
>I don't want it to display it at 5m/s (18 km/h)
,.. Which do you want?

Comment: m/s = meters per second the default value for the speed

Answer (score 0):

How about making a function of conversion like:

```
public float convertSpeedToKmH(float speed) {
 return speed * 3.6f;
}
```

Then instead of direct conversion, you call the function. Like:

```
float locationSpeedInKmH = convertSpeedToKmH(location.getSpeed());
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your calculations are wrong. Why are you doing `limit*3.6f`?

From this line: `setLimit.setText("Speed limit: " + (limit) + " km/h");`, the value of limit variable is already km/h. The conversion you're applying only works for transforming m/s to km/h. To convert km/h to m/s, you have to instead divide by 3.6.